# symbol not found in flat namespace '__PyTrash_begin

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I was trying to compile a code with instalooter login when I am getting this error symbol not found in flat namespace '__PyTrash_begin. all the other errors are mostly same but the end package looks very different

I havent tried anything yet in terms of solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.